# System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable:

Tags: apex, class, error, gack

I am having issues with one DML operation. This control is for an API that runs all day long, so jquery checks for the size of the list and when is equals to 0 it starts over again. So the page do not need human interaction at all if there are not errors. 
Sometimes I get this error:`System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable: The record you are attempting to edit, or one of its related records, is currently being modified by another user.` Before this error I was getting : `error:'Unable to lock row'` but someone advised me to use the code below and that error is gone. The ideal scenario would be: when there is an error, the page auto-refreshes. I will appreciate any help!

```
try{
     database.update(nr,false);

 }catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: can you change your app logic to be tolerant of this particular error and either ignore or retry later - rather than display the error?

Comment: crop1645, i am not very familiar with error handler. your suggestion is exactly what i am looking for. I want to ignore any errors but keep the application running. Could you please tell me how to this. I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: Note: when you use Database.update with second optAllorNone argument = false , no exception will be thrown. Instead, the results of the update are available in Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(nr,false) for inspection.  When doing SOQL, you can write multiple catch blocks after the try{blah = [select id, ...];} catch (QueryException qe) {..} catch (Exception e) {..}.  This gives you freedom to handle different types of errors in different ways

Comment: sorry to keep asking you about this but i want to undertand this issue. if i am using `database.update(nr,false);` why is the system throwing an exception? is because I did not specified the right exception inside the catch{..} Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are getting the `queryException` caught in the catch block in your posted code fragment?  You sure this exception isn't being thrown somewhere else?

Comment: yes i am 100% sure, that is the only DML in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16926/discussion-between-crop1645-and-carlos).